# ArcGIS 10.0 extensions not getting authorized after reinstall

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, license

I have reinstalled ArcGIS 10.0 and trying to authorized ArcEditor and other extensions. I am able to authorized ArcEditor whereas extensions are not getting authorized.

Any idea?

Comment: are you manually entering all the ECP or Unk codes for the extensions at install. If so what error are you getting? We also need to know if this is the student evaluation edition or the full purchased version or the higher education version.

Answer (score 1):

The extension are all purchases separately. For each one you purchase you will get a code.
http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/extensions

They typically cost a few thousand. Many people do not like this model of paying as much for the software as the extensions but that is the ESRI model. if you purchases extensions each one will have a unique activation code entered after the ArcEditor code. You can evaluate extensions free for 30 days.

Hope this helps. Basically each extension has a different code provided when you purchase it.